# Embeding React-Sigma-v2 component in another one throw "Container has no width" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

> Edit :
> Following further testing, this seems to be due to the fact that I'm trying to render multiple instances of a , as rendering only one is working as expected. I suspect this issue arose due to the multiple  tagged as a sigma root or because I'm trying to render the graphes through a Array.map. This issue is also encountered while using leaflet.js, which is similar in use's philosophy.

Using the provided example for a minimal react-sigma grap (https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/example) is non functionnal for using it inside another component.
The component I try to render :

```
export const MyGraph = (data) => {
 graph = treatData(data)
...
...
...
return(
  <SigmaContainer graph={graph} style={{ height: "500px",width: "500px" }}>
                <ControlsContainer position={"bottom-right"}>
                 .......
                </ControlsContainer>
              </SigmaContainer>
)
}
```

Rendering it in a empty page does not throw the "Container has no width error" and renders it as expected.
But rendering it inside another component (Such as a react-bootstrap Accordion component) makes it throw the width error.

I'm trying to have a component like this:

```
data.map((element)=> #Non proper JS syntax for simplification purposes
                   return(
                    <Accordion.Body
                      style={{
                        width: "500px",
                        height: "500px",
                        backgroundColor: "green",
                      }}
                    >
                      <div
                        style={{
                          width: "500px",
                          height: "500px",
                          backgroundColor: "green",
                        }}
                      >
                        <MyGraph data={element} style={{
                          width: "500px",
                          height: "500px"
                        }}/>
                      </div>
                    </Accordion.Body>)
```

It does not render, and the following error is thrown :

> Sigma: Container has no width. You can set the allowInvalidContainer setting to true to stop seing this error.

I already tried setting absolute height/width for the div, the container and the component, and the style sheet is imported as well.

Comment: Have you imported the CSS of the lib `import "@react-sigma/core/lib/react-sigma.min.css";` ?

Can you try to put the style directly on the `SigmaContainer`  like that : `<SigmaContainer style={{ height: "500px", width: "500px" }}>` ?

Comment: You should better check the code in the setup page instead of the one on the live example page